# R: random sample of columns excluding one column

Tags: r, sample

I may have discovered one of the problems in the code posted previously,  "R: using foreach() with sample() procedures in randomForest() call" and it relates to the script I was using to draw a random subsample of columns from a dataframe. 
The fake data (below) has 19 columns, "A" through "S" and I want to draw a random subset of 5 columns, but I want to exclude the third column, "C", from the draw.  Simply excluding the third column from the first argument of sample() call does not work (i.e., some of the samples contain the 'C' column). I'm hoping someone has a suggestion on how to do this. This is the script that does not work:

```
randsCOLs= sample(1:dim(FAKEinput[,c(1:2,4:19)])[2], 5, replace=FALSE) 
#randsCOLs= sample(dim(FAKEinput[,c(1:2,4:19)])[2], 5, replace=FALSE) - also doesn't work
out <- FAKEinput[,randsCOLs]

FAKEinput <- 
data.frame(A=sample(25:75,20, replace=T), B=sample(1:2,20,replace=T), C=as.factor(sample(0:1,20,replace=T,prob=c(0.3,0.7))),
    D=sample(200:350,20,replace=T), E=sample(2300:2500,20,replace=T), F=sample(92000:105000,20,replace=T),
    G=sample(280:475,20,replace=T),H=sample(470:550,20,replace=T),I=sample(2537:2723,20,replace=T),
    J=sample(2984:4199,20,replace=T),K=sample(222:301,20,replace=T),L=sample(28:53,20,replace=T),
    M=sample(3:9,20,replace=T),N=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),O=sample(0:5,20,replace=T),P=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),
    Q=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), R=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), S=sample(0:7,20,replace=T))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand - wouldn't `sample(names(FAKEinput[-3]), 5, replace = FALSE)` work?

Comment: `sample(names(FAKEinput)[names(FAKEinput) !='C'],5, replace=FALSE)
[1] "M" "P" "R" "L" "B"`

Comment: Yes. Sorry. My knowledge of R is spotty. Just saw your answers.

Comment: @KDA The above comment could be further shortened using `which` that gives a numeric index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like excluding the `dim()` call will work, if I'm not mistaken.

```
randsCOLs = sample(FAKEinput[-3], 5, replace=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more general approach (in case the `C` column is not the `3rd` column)

```
FAKEinput[sample(which(names(FAKEinput) !='C'),5, replace=FALSE)]
```

Or you could use `setdiff`

```
FAKEinput[sample(setdiff(names(FAKEinput),'C'), 5, replace=FALSE)]
```

Or by changing the OP's code of `1:dim` and assuming that `C` is the column `3`

```
FAKEinput[sample((1:dim(FAKEinput)[2])[-3], 5, replace=FALSE)]
```