# Sampling 1 specific column from a large set

Tags: r, random

I'm having some trouble randomly sampling 1 column out of a group. I have over 300 columns, and over 500 rows. I am attempting to sample 1 column out of the first 15, and then move on to sample 1 column from the next 15, etc... until there are no more.

For the basic first sample, I used:

```
sample(DATA[,1:15],1)
```

But it only outputs a single number. If I change my size to 535 (amount of rows), it grabs 535 random numbers in total from columns 1:15.

I referenced the below link, which had a somewhat similar basis, but the accepted answer is what I tried and can't seem to work:

[R: random sample of columns excluding one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746025/r-random-sample-of-columns-excluding-one-column)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer pretty quickly:

```
DATA[,sample(1:15,1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of a sample function is an integer. It should be used to *randomize* the column of the dataframe, not the entire dataframe, like you did earlier.

```
DATA[,sample(1:15,1)]
```

This will randomly select columns from 1 to 15 and will return the output as you desired.